# Writing file to remote server

Tags: c#, java, .net, video-streaming, aforge

I'm using this C# code, for acquiring the frames generated by the kinect device, and for writing these frames to .wmv file:

```
writer = new VideoFileWriter();
writer.Open("outputFileName.wmv", 320, 240, 15, VideoCodec.WMV2);

void client_ColorFrameReady(object sender, ColorFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
using (var frame = BitmapImage2Bitmap(e.ColorFrame.BitmapImage))
     using (var thumb = ResizeBitmap(frame, 320, 240))
     {
          writer.WriteVideoFrame(thumb);
     }      
}
```

When all the frames are written into the file, the file is closed (using `writer.Close()`) and sent to a remote server a Java application using [ftp client](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html).

Is there any way to write the file directly to the server, while it is still processing? Can I associate a writer to remote file? For example: `writer.Open("remoteServer\outputFileName.wmv", 320, 240, 15, VideoCodec.WMV2);` , or do I have to write first the entire file to local disk, then send it to the remote server?

Answer (score 0):

If the account the application is running under has permission to write to a folder on the server, then in theory you should be able to write to it.  You should be able to just use the UNC path for the server e.g.

```
\\remoteServer\path\to\outputFileName.wmv
```

However, you might find you experience problems due to network performance.  I guess the only way to know is to try it.